# Binary search recursive number of calls?

Tags: java, search, binary-search

So I was wondering, in my book, recursive binary search is implemented as follows:

```
 private static int bin(int[] arr, int low, int high, int target){
     counter++; //ignore this, it was to count how many calls this function invocated
     if(low > high) return -1;
     else{
         int mid = (low+high) / 2;
         if(target == arr[mid]) return mid;
         else if(target < arr[mid]) return bin(arr, low, mid-1, target);
         else return bin(arr, mid + 1, high, target);
     }

 }
```

And it says that "If n, the number of elements, is a power of 2, express n as a power of 2... Case 3: The key is not in the array, and its value lies between a[0] and a[n-1]. Here the number of comparisons to determine that the key is not in the array is equal to the exponent. There will be one fewer comparison than in the worst case."

But when I sat down and found the number of function calls using an array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9} and key of 8, the number of calls was 4. The book says the number of COMPARISONS is 3 (which is excluding the 3rd line I am guessing?), but I'm pretty sure the number of function calls is 4. I also generalized this to an iterative implementation of binary search and generalized that the number of iterations, OR recursive function calls, is always floor(log base 2 ( n ) ) + 1.

Can explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 3 `target == arr[mid]` comparisons are made. On the fourth iteration the base case `if(low > high)` is reached so the comparison is never made. As you stated: "Here the number of comparisons to determine that the key is not in the array is equal to the exponent." You are correct in that we are not dealing with the comparison statement on line 3. We are only concerned with the comparison statement for our target value.

Let's look at the iterations until either of the 2 base cases are reached.

Binary search for `8` in array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9}`

First iteration:

```
low = 0
high = 7
mid = 3
arr[mid] = 4
(target == arr[mid]) == false
```

Second iteration:

```
low = 4
high = 7
mid = 5
arr[mid] = 6
(target == arr[mid]) == false
```

Third iteration:

```
low = 7
high = 7
mid = 7
arr[mid] = 7
(target == arr[mid]) == false
```

Forth iteration:

```
low = 8
high = 7
low > high == true
```

Also, the Big O notation is O(log n). The + 1 is considered insignificant in Big O and therefore not counted. Please see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) on Wikipedia for order of Big O functions from fastest to slowest.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!